# How to use Auth0 login on iframe

Tags: angular, single-sign-on, auth0

I just implemented simple Angular based app with Login with Auth0 button. It works well when I open it directly on browser. I can log in with success. My aim is to have my app embedded into another web page using iframe (as kind of widget).

```
<div class="css"><iframe src="https://myapp.com"></iframe></div>
```

Login logic looks like this

```
login(redirectPath: string = '/') {
    this.auth0Client$.subscribe((client: Auth0Client) => {
      client.loginWithRedirect({
        redirect_uri: `https://some.now.sh`,
        appState: {target: redirectPath},
      });
    });
  }
```

But then during login I get an error

> There could be a misconfiguration in the system or a service outage.
>   We track these errors automatically, but if the problem persists feel
>   free to contact us. Please try again.
>
> invalid_request : You may have pressed the back button, refreshed
>   during login, opened too many login dialogs, or there is some issue
>   with cookies, since we couldn’t find your session. Try logging in
>   again from the application and if the problem persists please contact
>   the administrator.

On network tab i can see

> https://mycustomname.eu.auth0.com/authorize?xxxx

Which gets 302 with location

> /u/login?state=g6Fo2xxxxxxx

And then

> https://mycustomname.eu.auth0.com//u/login?state=g6Fo2xxxxxxx

Returns with 400 HTTP code.

What could be wrong ? It’s not possible to use Auth0 on iframe ?

Answer (score 8):

If you are using New Universal Login Experience, you will not be able to render Hosted Login page in Iframe. Auth0 includes the following HTTP headers to mitigate clickjacking attack.

```
X-Frame-Options: deny
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'none'
```

These headers blocks Iframe rendering. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

However, if you are using classic Unviersal login , you can turn off this feature which should allow the Hosted Login page in Iframe. As described here:

https://auth0.com/docs/migrations/guides/clickjacking-protection

Comment: Thanks :) It works bu there is another issue. When Auth0 classic login page is opened on iframe there is no possibility to log with google

Comment: Is there any way to disable clickjacking in new universal login page?

Comment: just enabling the clickjacking - iframe login working now 
https://auth0.com/docs/migrations/guides/clickjacking-protection